# Issue while downloading an Artifact from Artifcatory

Tags: maven, artifactory

Here I am having an issue while downloading the artifacts from the JFrog Artifactory. Below is the scenario where the download is failing.

- We have JFrog Artifactory as our repository management application. When we install our
  software it downloads the bundles/modules from JFrog repositories.
- We were installing our application in a very closed network. We only allow whitelisted
  IPs/domains to be allowed. We have whitelisted our JFrog URL, let it be <jfrogURL.jfrog.io> .
- But while downloading artifacts the application fails throwing connect exceptions from JFrog:

  - `prod-apse2-shared-sydney-main.s3.amazonaws.com:443`. i.e when we hit the jfrogURL.jfrog.io
  - local repository it is redirecting to `jfrog-prod-apse2-shared-sydney-main.s3.amazonaws.com:443`.
- Do they make any re-directions, when we access our URL i.e <jfrogURL.jfrog.io>? If so how can we whitelist these redirected URL/IP i.e is these URL is static one?

Can anyone please help us with these above queries?

Comment: For improved performance, JFrog saas Artifactory returns an S3 url for the downloaded artifact. Try whitelisting `jfrog-prod-apse2-shared-sydney-main.s3.amazonaws.com` and see if it helps.

Comment: If you have to use IPs, you can refer to official AWS doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html. Please report status, so we can put an official answer here for others facing similar challenges.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gradle project>>>
**After proxy setting** ( What is the proxy IP in your organization), I have added following code in **build.gradle** file. The problem has gone.

```
sourceSets {
main {
    output.setResourcesDir(java.outputDir)
   }
}
```

If you face same problem, please update gradle version